# Zend Lucene: Fatal Error, Maximum Execution Time

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I've written a basic indexing script for my site and it seems to be working...somewhat. It gets through about 3/4 of the pages it needs to index and then give this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded in
>   /Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer.php on line 166

It seems to hang up in a different spot each time, too. I ran it a minute later and got this:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded in
>   /Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/Directory/Filesystem.php on line 349

Here's the script:

```
foreach($all_items as $item) {
    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title', $item['pagetitle']));

    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('url', $item['url']));

    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('country', $item['country']));

    // Add document to the index
    $index->addDocument($doc);
}
```

Comment: Does the error message really say 0 seconds exceeded? Usually `set_time_limit(0);` means no limit

Comment: Yep, that is the error verbatim. I believe it is currently set to no time limit.

Comment: On a sidenote : indexing is a lot faster when using the Java implementation. I'd personally recommend using Solr (refer to the [PHP Solr documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) for more information). Setup might be a bit hard, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your task is time consuming?
Then increase time limit [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

```
 set_time_limit(0); //no time limit
 set_time_limit(500) //500 sec limit
```

Try increasing [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000);
```

There is also [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)

```
 ini_set('max_input_time', 5000);
```

If it still does not work, you will need to track down parts what is executing forever