# Yet another weird Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded, while pg_query() this time

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a php script processing some big data from database. It takes it from table by N(tried from 100 to 100000) rows and inserts it other table. `max_execution_time` is set to 0. Every iteration is wrapped in transaction. When selecting each portion I use `pg_query()`. But after 1-2 hours my script fails with `Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded`, with error message pointing to the line with `pg_query()`. Did anyone have this issue? Any cure?

**UPD**:

Having tried the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853220/zend-lucene-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time) -- setting max_input_time to -1 -- still have no luck. The error moved from `pg_query` line to another line, which seems to be a pretty random one. So `pg_query` I guess has nothing to do with that, as well as `max_input_time`.

Comment: what is your max_execution_time set as in php.ini or in your script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Lucene: Fatal Error, Maximum Execution Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853220/zend-lucene-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time)

Comment: @djjjuk It's zero, updated the post.

Comment: @Gordon thz, I'll check it out

Comment: make sure to update your post if that is NOT solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get that setting from? From a php.ini file? If so, search your project code for `ini_set`'s, they have higher priority. I bet there is one that silently creeped in.

Comment: Gotcha, it was it :)

Answer (score 1):

`max_execution_time = 0` means *run forever*.

However there might be other things that may stop your script. For example apache has a default script execution timeout of 5 minutes.

see this: [Is ini_set('max_execution_time', 0) a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306605/is-ini-setmax-execution-time-0-a-bad-idea)